# TextBlock with vertical scrollbar only

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I have a `TextBlock` which may contain a long text so I want to add a vertical scroll bar to it. My initial attempt was to wrap a `ScrollViewer` around it. That works but the problem is that when I zoom in, the width is zoomed also. I tried disabling the horizontal scroll bar like this:

`<ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">`

But it didn't solve the problem. I also tried binding the width:

`Width="{Binding ElementName=Scroller, Path=ViewportWidth}"`

It didn't help either.

So, my question is, how can I add vertical scrollbar to it but have a fixed width and wrapped text for the `TextBlock` inside? Here's my full code:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" IsTabStop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"  TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: How are you 'zooming in'?  Do you have a `viewbox` wrapped around your `scrollviewer`?

Comment: No. I just Ctrl+Scroll for zoom. I don't have a `ViewBox`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two parts to this answer... the first is to simply use a `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Text="Something really 
    really really really really really really really really long" 
    Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
```

The second part is to simply `Style` the `TextBox` so that it *looks* like a `TextBlock`:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Feel free to remove any of these properties if they do not suit your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll change the control to `TextBox`

Answer (score 1):

```
  <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    TextAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"/>
```

You don't need a `ScrollViewer` wrapped in the `TextBox`, the `TextBox` control has its own `ScrollViewer`. And you need to define the width of the `TextBox` so that the scrollbar will know its fixed width and will wrap the text.

Then, you have to style the TextBox to look like a `TextBlock`

A good reason why this `ScrollViewer` won't work according to to Ifeanyi Echeruo from Microsoft, from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb179a88-5dfd-490f-a4fe-5743200c12f3/wrapping-textblock-in-scrollviewer-any-elegant-solution)

> ScrollViewer first asks its content how large it would like to be in
>   the absence of constraints, if the content requires more space than
>   the Viewer has then its time to kick in some ScrollBars
>
> In the absence of constraints TextBlock will always opt to return a
>   size where all text fits on a single line.
>
> A ScrollViewer with ScrollBars will never get a TextBlock to wrap.
>
> However you may be able to come up with a Measure\Arrange combination
>   for a panel of your own that is almost like ScrollViewer but I cant
>   think of any logic that can satify both constraints without explicit
>   knowlege of the behaviour of said children

Comment: -1 because there is so much wrong with your answer. Your code says `TextBlock`, but your description says `TextBox`. Also, there is no `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property in the `TextBlock` class... maybe you were thinking about the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` attached property? This doesn't seem to work on a `TextBlock` though.

Comment: My bad, that was suppose to be TextBox. It should be obvious that my explanation mentioned TextBox not TextBlock, I made a mistake copying his code.